# MYSQL data randomly missing from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a social login system using php and mysql, the social login is setup for multiple venues. each venue has a database which data is inserted. as well as data being inserted in the venue database there is also a mysql trigger on all venues databases which insert the data into one big database.

The issue is sometime data is being missed from the venues database but i can see it in the big database, for example the venue database would record the name but will not record their email, however when i search the name in the big database i can see the email.

I'm thinking it may be something to do with the mysql triggers, this is happening randomly. Out of about 1000 there will be 50 with missing information.  below is the sql file which is the template for all venues databases.

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger user_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE db varchar(50);
SELECT database() INTO db;
call insert_update_master_user(NEW.id,NEW.email,db);
END $$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
create trigger user_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE db varchar(50);
SELECT database() INTO db;
call insert_update_master_user(NEW.id,NEW.email,db);
END $$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_update_master_user`(IN uid int(1), IN uemail varchar(255), IN udb varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE puc int(10); 
DECLARE i_first_name VARCHAR(30); 
DECLARE i_last_name VARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE i_age INT(10); DECLARE i_picture VARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE i_last_logined DATETIME; 
SET puc = (SELECT COUNT(1) AS c FROM login_master.users WHERE email=uemail); 
IF puc>0 THEN

 SELECT first_name,last_name,age,picture,last_logined INTO i_first_name,i_last_name,i_age,i_picture,i_last_logined 
 FROM users WHERE id=uid;  
 UPDATE login_master.users set first_name=i_first_name, last_name= i_last_name, age= i_age, last_logined = i_last_logined, loggedinto = concat(replace(loggedinto,concat(udb,'|'),''),udb,'|') 
 WHERE email = uemail;  

 ELSE
 INSERT INTO login_master.users (provider,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,age,picture,created,token_key,last_logined,loggedinto) 
 select  u.provider,u.first_name,u.last_name,u.email,u.gender,u.locale,u.age,u.picture,u.created,u.token_key,u.last_logined,concat(udb,'|') 
 from users u where u.id=uid; 
 END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```